# Remove Index and columns on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this list:

```
import pandas as pd
l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
New_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(l)
print(New_dataframe)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

I want to remove those indexed rows and columns. How to achieve that??DataFrame I would like to see is this:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

How to remove that index column and rows??

Comment: `New_dataframe.values`

Comment: can you elaborate more? @liliscent

Comment: @ShubhamKuse - What is reason for it?

Comment: I have responded to your thread @jezrael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If want see only values is possible convert to `2d numpy array`:

```
print (New_dataframe.values)
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```

If need see `DataFrame` it is possible by:

```
print (New_dataframe.to_csv(index=False, header=None, sep=' '))
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

print (New_dataframe.to_string(index=False, header=None))
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

EDIT:

For convert to excel without index and headers use parameter `index=False` and `header=None`:

```
New_dataframe.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False, header=None)
```

Comment: okay so i want to convert it into excel file without the index columns and rows?can you guide me on that?